# Manual T-Lock garage door locked, closed, and unhooked

Tags: garage-door

I'm in the process of trying to change out a T-Lock handle on a free standing garage/garage door. There is not a normal door.

I undid the t-lock that was in the door and went to install the new one. Realizing that it was too short, I went short the garage and from muscle memory closed it all the way.

The position I'm in now is that the new, incompatible t-handle in the door is in the lock, the keys are inside the garage, but none of that matters because the handle isn't hooked up anyway. Is there anyway to free a garage door from the outside? My problem revolves less around the lock and more around the door being shut. I can not access the interior of the garage currently.

Comment: Is the problem that it will not turn and undo the catch, or is it locked?  Of course everything you need is also in the garage?

Comment: It is locked but not hooked up to the pulley system. For all intents and purposes, its like the handle is not there.

Comment: Any windows or large enough vents to try(breaking) to get in?  Door might be able to be forced up if the catches will bend before the door does.  Some catches not that strong.  Would nice if somehow could hook onto the cables and pull.  Bet the door is tight to the bottom.

Comment: Sounds like it's time to buy a prehung door (or a window just bitg enough to crawl through if that's more economical) and a saw to cut the hole to put it into.